# Simple repeat notification

Tags: engraving, repeats

Trying to script in musical notation a section of music that plays repeatedly within a tune without writing it out multiple times and I'm getting confused with some of the notation symbols. In the example below, 'A' is a section of music that I want to execute once when it appears then twice more. In computer  programming lingo it would be a method or function call where you define a block of code ONCE and execute it multiple times elsewhere in the code. Probably what's causing my confusion!

```
| -music- | 'A' | -more music- | execute 'A' |
| -even more music- | execute 'A' | -still more music- |
```

Comment: It's often easiest to just copy the section.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer provided by Aaron is kind of correct, I don't recommend following it. This is not a standard practice. See, for example Mozart's Rondo from Horn Concerto in Eb, K495, https://dme.mozarteum.at/DME/nma/nma_cont.php?vsep=141&gen=edition&l=1&p1=77, theme (Section A) comes in measures: 1, 68, 125, and the last one in 183, modified, each time written out.

Unless for some reason you must strongly limit the space used by the score, it is typically better to write down the repeating musing rather than to introduce a non-standard repetition notation.

1. The score written this way difficult to read.
2. If the score extends to multiple pages, turning pages adds some inconvenience, but turning pages back and forth adds much more of it.
3. You may find that you want to make each `A` section very slightly different. Perhaps you will want to change something in the repetition to add interest. It might be as simple as dynamic marks. Perhaps the performer would like to mark it.

Answer (score 0):

If the section to be repeated is brief — say, one or two measures — it should be written in full each time.

For a longer section, the music given in the question would be written using numbered volta. The numbers indicate which measure(s) to play after repeating "A" for the *n*th time.

[image: Voltas combined with "To [rehearsal letter]" indications]

In programming terms, this is like the pre-function days when one used `goto` and `return`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can see the flow now, though it took a wee while for it to sink in.   P.S. Haven't used 'goto' and 'return' since the old COBOL days :-)!

Comment: Writing something like this is a guaranteed way to waste rehearsal time.

Comment: The reference to `goto` demonstrates how confusing such music notation can be.

Comment: Some of my charts are already 10 pages long. Turning pages isn't practical, and having to go back for a repeat somewhere isn't always successful. Moral being - don't be the keyboard player...